# Creating multi-line horizontally scrollable fixed width column grid using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, css-grid

I have a variable number of input boxes inside a bootstrap grid layout with four col-md-3 columns as displayed in the attached image below.

I would like this grid to scroll horizontally once 12 names are displayed (4 col x 3 rows). Therefore, according to this grid, instead of displaying all of the names in a page, the last two names would be listed as the first two input elements once the user scrolls to the right.

[Image of the grid I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZsI4.png)

Any solution would do! However a flexbox solution would be awesome!

Cheers!

Code:

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <form id="sterilizeForm" class="form-group ">
    <div class="row mx-2 mt-2 cleaners">
      @foreach( $cleaners as $key => $cleaner )
          <div class="cleaner col-md-3 span4 input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text" id="{{$cleaner->id}}">
                      {{$cleaner->name}}
                  </span>
              </div>

              <select name="options" class="">
                     <option value=''>Select one</option>
              </select>

          </div>
      @endforeach()
    </div>
    
   <button  class="log d-flex btn btn-primary btn-lg " type='submit'>
      Print
   </button>
 </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: if you can post your code then I can look into it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or post some code snippet ? It will be easier to answer question

Comment: I have added the code snippet. It has laravel blade templating and wont run as a snippet . No external css has been added aside from the bootstrap classes. Thanks!